# What about Programmer "Invisible" registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

These are **"Programmer Visible"** x86-64 registers:

[image]
<sub>(source: [usenix.org](http://www.usenix.org/events/bsdcon/full_papers/linden/linden_html/reg.gif))</sub>

What about the invisible registers? Just now I learned that MMU registers, Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT)  uses these invisible registers. I'm learning these things in the hard way. Is there any resource (book/documentation/etc) that gives me the complete picture at once?

I am aware of the programmer visible registers and comfortable in programming with them. I just want to learn about invisible registers and their functionality. I want to get a complete picture. Where can I get this info?

EDIT:

> I want to get a complete picture. Where can I get this info?

These are the two books helped me understanding these all low level details.

1. [**Fundamentals of Computer Organization and Design ~ Sivarama P. Dandamudi - 1 edition (2003**)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038795211X)
2. [Computer Organization and Design : The Hardware/Software Interface, 4th Edition, ~ David A. Patterson, John L. Hennessy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123744938)

Comment: If they're invisible, then why do you care? They are an implementation detail of the particular chip, and could actually change in the next stepping.

Comment: Well, to understand concretely about MMU (How it works?) and IDT to know how it manages interrupts.

Comment: @John: Excellent and concise comment and it shows that relying on 'undocumented/invisible' registers can break....+1 from me... @Claws: Stick to the visible registers to guarantee future of program/software

Comment: @tommieb75 Knowing about them makes things more clear and helps me understanding how things are implemented. Even if they change it future. It still leaves me with some idea about implementation of some concepts.

Yeah, I'm not going to depend on them. Its just for learning.

Comment: Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain!

Comment: I'm actually surprised by these comments. I agree with you guys that one shouldn't depend on  'undocumented/invisible' things. But why are you guys being so rigid about this opinion. As an internal's enthusiast. Why shouldn't we learn about these things? I hope you guys know about "Protected Mode Addressing" & "Segmentation Address Translation". Did you ever wonder how CPU manages these things? It does this using these invisible registers. http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~cpatel2/links/310/slides/chap17_lect15_segmentation.pdf Isn't it informational to learn?

Comment: @claws: it's not informational to learn about something specific to a particular implementation of an architecture. It can change on the next chip in the series. How many different implementations do you want to have clogging up your head? Don't bother learning the implementation - learn the result of the implementation.

Comment: @John Saunders: There is nothing wrong (and plenty right) with being interested in how things work under the hood. Your argument is equivalent to claiming that people who code in C or any higher level language shouldn't learn assembly because it's an implementation detail. You can't directly access any CPU registers through (standard) C, just as you can't access invisible registers through assembly. That doesn't mean it's wrong to want to learn what registers are and how they fit into the computer architecture, or at the lower level, to want to understand how invisible registers are used.

Comment: @John: no, it's not. I'm talking about registers that are part of the implementation of the chip, or which are part of the _very_ low-level structure. If you're writing Operating System code, then you need to know about these. Otherwise, you don't.

Comment: @John: The *need* to know is different from the *desire* to know, and I see nothing whatsoever wrong with having the desire to know.

Comment: @John: the question is whether you desire to know things that are implementation-specific, so that they should never be used in anything but an operating system.

Comment: @John: There's nothing wrong with desiring to know things that are implementation specific, as long as you're aware that that's the case. Also, what is considered to be implementation specific depends entirely on what level of abstraction you're working at. If you're working at the level of C code, then machine instructions and visible CPU registers are an implementation specific detail (hence the equivalence I indicated in my first comment).

Comment: "Hidden" does not necessarily imply "implementation specific". For simple examples; consider architectural MSRs (literally registers that are hidden from user-space but have become a standardized part of the architecture) and the parts of segment registers that are hidden from kernel code (but exposed to SMM and virtual machine monitors in a standardized way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDT is an Interrupt Descriptor Table, which contains something like this from an abstract view, first eighteen interrupts are reserved by the processor, the next eighteen are reserved by Intel for future proofing the architecture of the chip...

```
Interrupt    Handler
   0         divide_by_zero_handler
   1         debug_handler
   ..           ...
   13        general_exception_handler
   14        page_fault_handler
   ..           ...
   18        machine_check_handler
```

In this context, the handlers are part of a toy kernel, and each of the handlers are set up at boot time, prior to user-land code being loaded. (BIOS is 16 bit code aka real mode code), kernel sets up the handlers, switches to 32bit protected mode, when any of the interrupts are issued, the appropriate handler is executed depending on the Interrupt number. For example, if interrupt 14 was generated, the kernel will execute a `page_fault_handler`, check if the page is dirty and reside on disk, then load that page into memory, fix up the addresses and clear the dirty bit, executes an `IRET` Interrupt Return instruction to continue, clearing the flags....

That is an abstract view of how IDT works...There is more complex things going on behind the scenes...depending on the architecture and type of memory management such as paged/flat/protected/virtual mode addressing schemes...

Have a look here at the [Intel](http://www.intel.com/design/pentium/MANUALS/241430.htm) documentation that gives an excellent and thorough view of the Intel programming...

**Edit:**
Back in the old days of DOS (which was 16bit code and not well, exactly memory protected), it was possible to re-route the interrupt handlers to your own handlers thus overlaying the original IDT, for an example of such an interrupt, Interrupt 9 which is the Keyboard Interrupt (BIOS interrupts in this context) using the `getvect(...)` and `setvect(...)` calls, you could also, handle some (not all of the processor interrupts, notably, IDT 0 for divide by zero)...although those BIOS interrupts were quite similar in appearance to the processor interrupts, they shared a common feature, both did have the table of interrupt vectors (as it was known back then). That was how TSR (Terminate Stay Resident) programs were able to keep re-entrant in DOS as a result of the BIOS interrupts re-routed to the TSR's handlers...

Comment: You don't even mention IDTR, the internal IDT base/limit register loaded by the [`lidt` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt) that tells the CPU where to find the IDT.  I assume this is what @claws meant when they said the IDT uses an internal register?  Other internal regs include the segment base/limit settings loaded from the GDT when writing a selector to a segment reg in protected mode.  (Or for FS/GS, but modifying the base via an MSR with `wrmsr`)

Comment: Also, in real mode, you have an IVT (Interrupt *Vector* Table, because they're just pointers not descriptors).  You mention this later, but it wasn't just a different name for the exact same thing.  And BTW, software interrupts share the same interrupt-number "address space" as async HW-generated interrupts.  e.g. I think you really could run an `int 9` instruction to make the system run the keyboard-interrupt handler.  AFAIK it was simply up to software not to do that in ways that would lock up the system, because everything ran in ring 0; that's why you could hook an interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to study the processor reference manual for the particular processor you're interested in. Here's the [Itanium Processor Reference Manual](http://www3.intel.com/design/itanium/downloads/245320.htm).

Comment: The question is about x86-64 not Itanium.